# How to search one certain field’s value with not unique results on elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, bigdata

Need some advise.
I have indexed documents in elasticsearch, now i want to search all results with one certain field value with all related document, like following if i search for reportId=12345, the results will have several documents related, how can i use one api to get results with not unique on certain field

```
   POST myindex/type/_search
    {
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "reportId": "12345"
          }
        }
}
```